# Is the "which" unnecessary?

Tags: grammaticality

Why do I have to add "which" in this sentence?

> What are some dinosaurs in which the fossilized remains of plants have been found?

Comment: The question wouldn't make sense without it.

Comment: Your sentence makes no sense. What is it that you are trying to say?

Comment: There are no dinosaurs in which anything has been found. Dinosaurs are extinct. Do you mean *What are some fossilized dinosaur remains in which the fossilized remains of plants have also been found?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this question, or in general in this sentence, you talk about a location. That's why you need to provide a preposition in between. It could've been "that" which would be a little more informal.

So, since it is a location, two options left: "where" and "in which". Although many people are confused by these two and standalone "which", "in which" can be used instead of "where". ("which" cannot) If you remove it, you remove the preposition, and the sentence become meaningless or it becomes obvious that the user lacks of essential information in sentence-building.

**In addition,** **for those who are interested,** I think there is a nuance between "in which" and "where". I have not read any official statement about this, or about if there any, but sometimes if the location is more object-based I prefer to use "in which" rather than "where". It also makes the sentence more formal.

I know object-based is kind of a definition of mine and may not make sense at first. Let me give an example. You can call it whatever you want.

**I'd use,**

This is the computer in which the virus was discovered.

**But preferably not,**

This is the computer where the virus was discovered.

**However, I'd say,**

This place, where he lives, is a pretty nice spot.

**But not,**

This place, in which he lives, is a pretty nice spot.

To me, all are acceptable but I would what I indicated. I think it is also highly related to context and formality.

For more information, [here](http://www.englishbaby.com/lessons/2824/member_submitted/how_to_use_in_which) may help, too.

Hope these help.